# Java: Can I import an action listener that disables a swing component?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JButton on an extension of a JForm called MyForm. The button executes quite lengthy code. Amongst this code is 'MyForm.this.setEnabled(false)' to disable the form whilst the button method executes. (And subsequently, 'MyForm.this.setEnabled(true)'.)

(I do this because it is the only solution I have found for ensuring that any mouse-clicks during the button's execution are ignored. Otherwise, I've found they queue up and execute immediately afterwards).

Can I export this button's code to some other file, for importing into a variety of other forms?

EDIT: Code:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Button Text");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        MyForm.this.setEnabled(false);
        ...
        MyForm.this.setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: You could define your custom ActionListener class in it's own file.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it references a parent class, MyForm. How can I separate them?

Comment: I'd like it to act on whatever form the button is on, so that I can reuse the button on multiple forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the form to disable as argument to the constructor of your listener:

```
public class FormDisablingActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private final Form formToDisable;

    public FormDisablingActionListener(Form formToDisable) {
        this.formToDisable = formToDisable;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        this.formToDisable.setEnabled(false);
        ...
        this.formToDisable.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

BTW, that's what the compiler generates for you when using an anonymoous class referencing its outer class instance like you're doing.

Then use it the following way:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Button Text");
myButton.addActionListener(new FormDisablingActionListener(this));
```

Comment: This approach looks like it will work. However, I get the error: 
"The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (FormDisablingActionListener)"

Comment: The message is clear. It indicates that I simply forgot to make this class implement the ActionListener interface. Fixed now.

Comment: Ah, yep that's all working perfectly now. Thanks for your help!